.NET 8.0 Windows - required files to distribute a new version of an application
We just have upgraded a vb.net windows forms runtime app to .NET 8.0.
Regarding the runtime, we use “Self contained”.
So… the runtime to .NET 8.0 and the APP are stored in the same directory.
Now, the question is, which files have to be updated for a new version of the .exe?
With .NET 8.0, there are a few new config files…
If we create a new build, the following files are updated:

Appname.dll and Appname.exe ( 1 ):
These files have to be updated for sure, as they contain the app code.
Further files:
Appname.runtimeconfig.json
Appname.deps.json
Appname.application
Appname.dll.manifest
Appname.xml
Appname.pdb:
I think, this file is obsolete, as it should contain debug information’s.
Can somebody explain which of the additional files have to be distributed with a new .exe version (in addition to Appname.dll and Appname.exe)?
Thanks

I suggest making a test system will all of them, then removing one file at a time. If it breaks, put the file back and try the next file. When you're done, you'll have the minimum set. Best way to learn.

The following documents need to be included:
Appname.runtimeconfig.json
Appname.deps.json
Appname.dll.manifest
Appname.application
